# Deleter file counter works, but give random numbers

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I made a counter to delete from a minecraft save `level.dat_old` file, like this:

```
@echo off
:asd
:E
if not exist level.dat_old goto asd
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@echo off

set /a counter=1

for /r %%f in (*) do (
  set /a counter=!counter!+1
  if exist level.dat_old del level.dat_old
  if exist level.dat_old echo Level dat deleted !counter! times!
  
)
goto asd
```

Deletes files properly, but deleter counter gives crazy random numbers, this prints:

> ```
> Level dat deleted 2 times
> Level dat deleted 2 times
> Level dat deleted 36 times
> Level dat deleted 84 times
> ```

Answer (score 1):

<s>set /a counter=!counter!+1</s>
if exist level.dat_old del level.dat_old&set /a counter+=1

The "crazy numbers" are generated because your code increments `counter` for *every* file located. It might also be an idea to start the counting more conventionally at zero, not 1.